# How can I adjust the weight of frame layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

So I'm trying to adjust the weight of frame layout so it can overlay the whole page of the activity. [Result of what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUVet.png)

This is my xml for the current activity I'm in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/passion_one"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Kung Fu Tea Order"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="393dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addAnotherDrink"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape"
        android:fontFamily="@font/passion_one"
        android:text="ADD ANOTHER DRINK"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/placeOrderBtn"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape"
        android:fontFamily="@font/passion_one"
        android:text="PLACE ORDER"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/_dynamic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-90dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        tools:ignore="UnknownId" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In my java class, I'm basically using a button to navigate to a fragment by using a frame layout as a container.

So really, is there a way to change the weight of this frame layout so my previous activity won't show?

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s handle only `Fragment`s' `View`s. You should put the original content – i.e, the `<TextView>`, `<ListView>`, etc. – into its own `Fragment` that you load at startup, and can `replace()` with your other `Fragment`s as needed.

Comment: Are you saying making another container to put my fragments in so it can replace my other fragments?

Comment: I'm meant that, if you want to replace the `Activity`'s entire layout with your `Fragment`, then your `Activity`'s layout should be just the container `FrameLayout`, and all of the stuff you have there now should be in its own `Fragment`. You would load that `Fragment` at startup, in `onCreate()`. Then, when you want to switch, use a `replace()` transaction for the new `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the base of the whole activity a frame layout. Then you can layer layouts on top of each other, so FrameLayoutBase > RelativeLayout from above > FrameLayout you want to overlay across the whole screen. Then just adjust the visibility of the layout as needed. NOTE: the Relative Layout and the Overlay FrameLayout are both SEPARATE children of the FrameLayoutBase.